# Write and Activerecord join query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm writing an activerecord join query but It doesn't work.

I have these two classes

```
class User
  belongs_to :store, required: true  
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, dependent: :nullify
  has_one :manager, -> { where role: User.roles[:manager] }, class_name: 'User'
end
```

I need to get all the stores with a manager and all the stores without a manager.

I write these two queries

```
Store.includes(:users).where('users.role <> ?', User.roles[:manager]).references(:users).count

Store.includes(:users).where('users.role = ?', User.roles[:manager]).references(:users).count
```

and the result is

```
2.2.1 :294 > Store.includes(:users).where('users.role <> ?', User.roles[:manager]).references(:users).count
   (6.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "stores"."id") FROM "stores" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."store_id" = "stores"."id" WHERE (users.role <> 1)
 => 201
2.2.1 :295 > Store.includes(:users).where('users.role = ?', User.roles[:manager]).references(:users).count
   (4.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "stores"."id") FROM "stores" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."store_id" = "stores"."id" WHERE (users.role = 1)
 => 217
```

Now I know that I have 219 stores, and using

```
with_manager = 0
without_manager = 0
Store.all.each do |s|
 if s.manager.present?
  with_manager = with_manager +1
 else
  without_manager = without_manager +1
 end
end
```

I know also that I have 217 stores with manager and 2 store without manager. One query is working, the second (stores without manager) fails.

So I must fix the query, but I cannot understand how can I fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use the following thing for, getting al stores with a manager:

```
Store.joins(:manager)
```

Joins will use a inner join and not a left join that is includes case.

In the opposite case, that's tricky, but I do in this way:

```
Store.includes(:manager).where(users: { id: nil })
```

It's a left join with manager and getting all stores without a user included.